# Redirect cin (c++) to multiple files in cmd

Tags: windows, file, cmd, cin

I have been searching it, but I cant manage to found the way. Basically I have two files: "hello.txt" and "bye.txt":

hello.txt:

> 1 2 3 8 8

bye.txt:

> 9 9 8 1 2

I know how to redirect `cin` to `hello.txt` using:

```
a.exe < hello.txt
```

So cin will recieve `"1 2 3 8 8"`. But how can I make it to recieve info from both files `"1 2 3 8 8 9 9 8 1 2"`. I have already tried to duplacate the `<`:

```
a.exe < hello.txt < bye.txt
```

But it didnt work, I also tried this:

```
a.exe < hello.txt <& bye.txt
```

But from what I read it wont work (It didnt). Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @DrewDorman I seriously doubt you edit is helpful. The question is clearly related to a windows environment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The [tag:windows-shell] tag was not appropriate. Did you not read the tag wiki summary before deploying it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not relevant to C++.
Either you could change the code and read from many files provided as command line or you redirect first all files in one and read that one then:

```
type hello.txt > tmp.txt
type bye.txt >> tmp.txt
e.exe < tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If available on your system, you can use [`cat`](http://man.cx/cat) for this:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | a.exe
```

See it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c3bfe6b8afbfc73).

Comment: I was about to write the same answer until I've spotted `a.exe`. I doubt, a windows environment supports `cat` without MSys.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'll just leave it here, maybe a Linux user with the same problem will drop by in the future. Besides, there is no windows tag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But you are right, even Nuwen's MinGW bundle comes without `cat`.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to note it. As mentioned your proposal should at least work  under windows, from a MSys shell. And the standard executable name `a.exe` leaves me with the impression the OP actually uses MinGW GCC.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've asked this on Stack Overflow, and not Super User, here is a poor man's cat implementation, in C++, with a lot of room for improvement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        std::ifstream fin(argv[i]);
        std::cout << fin.rdbuf();
    }
}
```

If you compile this to a program called cat, you can then use it like this:

```
cat hello.txt bye.txt | a.exe
```

Although I'm sure there are proper full-featured implementations of cat for Windows out there if you look.

My personal preference on Windows would be to switch to Powershell and use [`Get-Content`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx).

```
Get-Content hello.txt, bye.txt | a.exe
```